# how to pass the value of a variable from View to Controller in js

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, express, model-view-controller

I have a program on the Mongo, Express, Node js stack in which I implemented the MVC template. The View folder contains two html files displaying pages in `/` and in `/test/example`. Also in the View folder is a js file (`main.js`), which calculates the value of some variable (`points`) based on the data entered by the user on the `/` page. I need to pass points from this js file to a function in the controller (`module.exports.doCreate`), which is located in the `homepage.js`, in order to further pass its value to the Mongodb database via the API. Also, the function in the controller sends not only points, but also several other values that the user fills in already on the `/test/example page`.

part of the file system structure:

```
views/
├─ main.js
├─ index.html
├─ create-form.html
controllers/
├─ homepage.js
```

`homepage.js`

```
...
module.exports.doCreate = function(req, res) {
    var postdata = {
        age: req.body.age,
        // points: points, // here you need to pass points
        xray: req.body.xray
    };
    console.log(postdata);
    axios.post('https://some.domain/api/users', postdata, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
}
...
```

I tried using JQuery in main.js . When clicking on the button with the id `req_api_but`, (the button is on the page `/`), a redirect to `/test/example` should have occurred. On the `/test/example` page there is a form to submit, in one of the hidden fields of which the value `points` should have appeared, but this did not help.

```
$("#req_api_but").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get('/test/example', function (data) {
        window.location.href = '/test/example';
        $(data).find('#points').text(points);
    });
});
```